# is there a way to increase the length tooltip is displayed in asp.net chart?

Tags: asp.net, tooltip

I have a chart that displays a tooltip (string) when hovered over. Is there a way to control the delay/time the tooltip is displayed to the user?

```
<asp:Chart runat="server" ID="Chart2" Width="340px" Height="265px">
        <!--Define Things in here-->
    </asp:Chart>
```

Backend:

```
    //define what rec is
    string tooltip = rec;
    Chart2.ToolTip = tooltip;
```

Comment: Hi cfarm, are you using the new .Net 4.0 chart controls? If not, could you let us know the type of Chart2? Would it be possible to supply more (all) of the code, especially using, import and register statements in aspx and include statements in the code behind. It /might/ still be possible to do something with javascript, but we'd need a little more information to figure out the markup that makes it to the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but probably not.

Most tooltips are a browser feature, and display either the alt tag of an img, or the title tag of most elements. So the control of how long that tooltip displays is going to vary from browser to browser.

It's possible that the tooltip is under your control, and is an html element displayed with javascript on mouseover, or the charts and the tooltip might be in Flash or Silverlight, but if that's the case we'd need to see your code.

Answer (score 5):

I just came up with a pretty simple solution to this classic problem with the help of some Javascript I borrowed from here: http://bonrouge.com/~js_tooltip

Asp.NET renders tooltips as a title attribute on the actual HTML page generated. You can take advantage of this fact to apply whatever style you like to the tooltip by overriding it with two very simple javascript functions.

```
function showTooltip(control) {
    var ttext = control.title;
    var tt = document.createElement('SPAN');
    var tnode = document.createTextNode(ttext);
    tt.appendChild(tnode);
    control.parentNode.insertBefore(tt, control.nextSibling);
    tt.className = "tooltipCss";
    control.title = "";
}
function hideTooltip(control) {
    var ttext = control.nextSibling.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    control.parentNode.removeChild(control.nextSibling);
    control.title = ttext;
}
```

Next you need to design your css for your tooltip:

```
position:absolute; 
border:1px solid gray; 
width:300px; 
margin:1em; 
padding:3px; 
background: Red;
```

Finally you need to wire up the JavaScript to your control

```
Chart2.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "showTooltip(this)");
Chart2.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "hideTooltip(this)");
```

Hope this helps.... I've been looking for a SIMPLE way of doing Tooltips for all my Asp.Net stuff for ages. I don't like to declare my Tooltip code in separate spans or whatever as this is really no good for my dynamically generated stuff. Anyway I just wanted to add this somewhere online. Hope it helps someone out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing probably not.  If you need more flexibility I would recommend going with a jQuery tooltip solution.

Comment: I've tried qtip (jquery plugin). The problem with the tool is it renders outside the element. For example if I wrap the asp:Chart in a <a/> tag, then reference it to the plugin $('a').qtip{/*define properties*/} then it only renders a tooltip outside of the <a/>. I would like the tooltip to render in the chart itself and follow the mouse around.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Ravendarksky's answer: I used his code but if I moved my mouse during the mouseout event over the tooltip content, IE would issue an unhandled exception (no issues in Chrome, I did not check Firefox):

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'nodeValue' of undefined or null reference

So I simply wrapped the implementation of hideTooltip in a conditional checking for null and all was well in IE [and Chrome]:

```
function hideTooltip(control) {
    if (control.nextSibling.childNodes[0] != null) {
        var ttext = control.nextSibling.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        control.parentNode.removeChild(control.nextSibling);
        control.title = ttext;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use HoverMenuExtender of asp.net. You can also modify the pop up content/design.

Code reference sample here: http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2009/11/ajax-hovermenuextender-how-to-use.html